# Trying to wrap second map method in a row DIV but i keep getting unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 {middleMenu.map((column) => {
          return (
            <div className="row">
             column.map((item) => {
              const { title, image, path } = item;
              return (
                <ul className="footer-collections">
                  <MenuLinks title={title} image={image} path={path} />
                </ul>
              );
            })
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Does anyone know what the solution is? My first time using 2D Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :

```
  <div className="row">
         {column.map((item) => {
          const { title, image, path } = item;
          return (
            <ul className="footer-collections">
              <MenuLinks title={title} image={image} path={path} />
            </ul>
          );
        })}
        </div>
```